# Pandas read excel data by preserving the format

Tags: python, pandas

My excel file has following data.

```
df=3%   6%  7%  8%  7%
```

When I read it using pd.read_excel,

```
df=0.03 0.06 0.07 0.08 0.07
```

Is there a way to read the data so that the % symbol is retained too?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: try the ```dtype```  or ```converter``` option in ```pd.read_excel()``` and see if it preserves ur data type. if not, i'd suggest ```openpyxl``` to read in the data

Comment: _My excel file has following data. `df=3%   6%  7%  8%  7%`_ What? Those examples don't make much sense. Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, we can use `pandas.style.format`

actually pandas is reading those values correctly, as you have a styled version on top of your cell, if you inspect the cell you'll have something like this :

[image]

It's generally never recomended to alter your raw data for presentation purposes, use styling or html methods.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'foo' : [0.2,0.4], 'bar' : [0.6, 0.82]})

print(df)
   foo   bar
0  0.2  0.60
1  0.4  0.82


df.style.format({
    'foo': '{:.0%}'.format,
    'bar' : '{:.1%}'.format
})


    foo     bar
0   20%     60.0%
1   40%     82.0%
```